# Revise HTML Input Form format

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I used web crawler function download some webpages which contains some input from functions, likes:

```
<input type="text" name="LSTNAM" size="20" maxlength="35">
<input type="text" name="FSTNAM" size="20" maxlength="35">
```

Here I want to know whether I can use some **JS method** to **find all the ""input type="text"", and revised these forms** instead of just manually revise them one by one. Here is the target I want to achieve:

```
<input type="text" name="LSTNAM" size="20" maxlength="35"     onclick="shwinputtypetext(this);">
<input type="text" name="FSTNAM" size="20" maxlength="35" onclick="shwinputtypetext(this);">
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")` will fetch all the input elements of type text in the current document. What do you mean by revise the forms?

Comment: What I express is confused :), All I want to do is just change the content from first one to the later one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = function() {
        shwinputtypetext(this);
    }
}
```

For more information, see [MDN's documentation on `document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: +1 for not not using jQuery where vanilla js is more than sufficient!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easily by JQuery, try to use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type='text']").click(function(){
        //do some stuff, exp:
        alert($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the easiest way to solve your problem. Hope it will help. Write less and do more..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(":input[type='text']").click(function(){

        shwinputtypetext($(this).val());

    });

});
```